# VueJS - v-model table represented as 2D Array

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a simple table and the data are represented as an `Array` or `Array`s:

```
[
["January",null,null,null],
["February",null,null,null],
["March",null,null,null],
["April",null,null,null],
["May",null,null,null],
["June",null,null,null],
["July",null,null,null],
["August",null,null,null],
["September",null,null,null],
["October",null,null,null],
["November",null,null,null],
["December",null,null,null]
]
```

I want to display this table and `v-model` every cell so the `data.table` is changed anytime a user change the table.

I was checking for some solutions like `Hansontable` but I think it's overkill. Is there some simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in this way.
Just add `v-model` directive when generating a table.

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <th>month</th>
      <th>some</th>
      <th>some</th>
      <th>some</th>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="(el, i) in array">
      <tr :key="i">
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input text" v-model="el[0]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input text" v-model="el[1]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input text" v-model="el[2]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input text" v-model="el[3]" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>

    <!-- rows for test -->
    <template v-for="(el, i) in array">
      <tr :key="i">
        <td>
          {{ el[0] }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ el[1] }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ el[2] }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ el[3] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
```